# Add minimizer_kwargs to scipy's differential evolution algorithm

Tags: python, scipy-optimize

I am using scipy.optimize.differential_evolution() for optimizing a black-box function that is evaluated using some simulations. I would like to use polish=True, so at the end the best candidate is optimized using local search algorithm L-BFGS-B. But this is useless in my case because the default step size for gradient determination is not appropriate.

Is there a simple way to change this? I tried the code given below but this gives an error as I expected.

`res = opt.differential_evolution(run, polish=True, minimizer_kwargs={'method': 'L-BFGS-B', 'options':{'ftol': ftol, 'gtol': gtol, 'eps': eps}})`

`TypeError: differential_evolution() got an unexpected keyword argument 'minimizer_kwargs'`

Comment: Hi Nik, Looks like the function doesn't support `minimizer_kwargs` and has never supported! I checked all the older versions of SciPy as well but couldn't find it. (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.differential_evolution.html). Has it ever worked for you before ?  Where did you get this code snippet?

Comment: No, it never worked for me. I created the snippet in analogy to the functions scipy.optimize.shgo() and scipy.optimize.basinhopping(). I only would like to know how/whether I can modify the local optimizer in differential evolution.

Comment: edit: reduced irrelevant parameters

Comment: Okay, the API (differential_equation) doesn't accept the parameter that you want to pass.  There is nothing much I can do.  If you think it is logical for differential_equation to accept such an argument, consider logging a feature request with SciPy.

Comment: Thank you @return007. I browsed pull requests on [scipy's github](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/13561), this one is on my question. I think for me the best way is to add the local minimizer after finishing differential evolution search using:
`minimizer_kwargs = {'method': 'TNC', 'bounds': bounds}                               
res = differential_evolution(func, bounds, polish=False)                            
minimize(func, res.x, **minimizer_kwargs)`